# Android ColorFilter - Porter-Duff Modes

Tags: android, colors, filter, porter-duff, colorfilter

I'm trying to solve a problem with android `ColorFilters`. Documentation is very poor, so the main method is trying different variants.

The problem:

There is a Bitmap. Some pixels have alpha=255, others have alpha=0. I'm trying to draw a circle with a specific color. I want alpha channel unchanged in the bitmap, but while drawing I want to multiply a color to the bitmap-alpha.

So, while drawing a circle I want pixels with alpha=0 to be not painted, but pixels with alpha=255 to be painted in color which I want. Alpha channel shouldn't change.

I'm trying to use porter-duff ColorFilter (PorterDuffColorFilter class in android sdk).

there are too many modes and no-understandable description on official site here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html

I think I should use `DST_ATOP` or `SRC_ATOP`, but they don't work as I described.

Also, there is a strange parameter `srcColor` in constructor of porter-duff colorfilter.

I can't understand what "Sa" and "Sc" means in formulas `[Da, Sc * Da + (1 - Sa) * Dc]`. It can be from color which was passed into colorfilter constructor and also it can be color set by "paint.setColor".

Anybody knows, how it works?

Comment: You could google porter duff to see what these modes mean.

Comment: This great document explains PorterDuff Modes with images: http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html   Just be aware it doesnt add "src_" like android does: so "IN" = "SRC_IN"

Answer (score 10):

`Sa` and `Sc` are shorts for "source alpha" and "source color", respectively. The `srcColor` parameter in the `PorterDuffColorFilter` constructor is the color used for these values.

For your case the `Mode.MULTIPLY` would probably work best.

Comment: But how paint.setColor affects on it? I tried to change it and understood that it affects! I think it should be in such blending formulas?

Comment: Also, multiply mode doesn't work in this case. Pixels with zero alpha channel are also painted :(

Comment: I am not entirely sure about this part, but I think that if you set a color to your paint, this value will somehow be included in one of the src/dst arguments at some point. It seems likely that the color alpha is also taken into the calculations in your case, making everything a solid 1.0-alpha. You should try to draw the bitmap without setting a color on the paint as well.

Comment: Hmmm... Is it right that "Da" is destination alpha - alpha-channel of bitmap in which i'm trying to draw (to be exact, I create a Canvas over bitmap and draw into that canvas)?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But it is not impossible that this value is also affected by your color.

Answer (score 5):

Note that Porter-Duff modes are only defined to work properly with premultiplied alpha. That means that none of the R, G or B components can exceed the alpha value.

[GitHub project](https://github.com/ldo/porter_duff_browser_android) for the Android project which shows off all the Porter-Duff modes. The [Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nz.gen.geek_central.porter_duff_browser&hl=en) is also available on Playstore.

Comment: the app shows how the formulas effect the images nicely. would be better if you include some simpler images as an option.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I came to following conclusions regarding PorterDuff Color modes in Android,

- Sa and Sc are Source Alpha and Source Color, 
  e.g. if I am setting ColorFilter to a drawable like        myDrawable.setColorFilter(desiredColor,Mode.SRC_ATOP) the Sa and Sc values will be taken from desiredColor not from myDrawable. Da and Dc will be original alpha and color values of myDrawable.
- I had an Image and I want to apply certain color with alpha values from user input. I tried to use PorterDuff Modes, My original myDrawable was a nine patch drawable and it had transparent background and trangular corners like messaging bubble triangles. When I used

  public static final PorterDuff.Mode SRC
   [Sa, Sc]

which applies Source color and Source Alpha, which I supposed Color and Alpha values of above setColorFilter method desiredColor, I got color values correct i.e. Color and alpha was correctly applied to new Drawable but triangle on that image was completely washed/removed. 
So I had to use ColorMatrixFilter and setup matrix and set alpha value separately to drawable.